# OpenCv image is not getting displayed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

Please have a look at the following code

```
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat image;

    try
    {
        image = imread("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Chrysanthemum.jpg");

        if(!image.data)
        {
            throw 1;
        }

        cout << "Height: " << image.size().height << " Width: " << image.size().width << endl;
    }
    catch(int error)
    {
        cout << "This message does not exists" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    namedWindow("Image 1");
    imshow("Image 1",image);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, I do not get the image displayed. Instead, a blank image is displayed. Why is that? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to let the window refresh.
system("pause") does not do it.
The opencv equivalent is
waitKey(0);